# Where does Python search for files when using open?

Tags: python

I have the simplest file opening line in my code.

```
file = open("file.txt", "r+")
```

Where does python search for files? The only location that works for me is

> C:/Users/*useraccount*

```
file = open("file.txt", "w")
```

This also creates the file in that specific location.

It won't open the file if the file is in the exact same folder as the python script itself.

Also, if I make it

```
file = open("folder/file.txt", "r+")
```

it will not open the file if the file is in `C:/Users/*useraccount*/`folder.

Is it possible to open files that aren't in that specific location?

Answer (score 3):

If you pass a relative path, like `file.txt`, Python will search for that file relative to the same directory where you are running the command from.

If you are in - `C:/Users/useraccount/` and you try to open `file.txt` then Python tries to open `C:/Users/useraccount/file.txt`.

Similarly, if it's `folder/file.txt` then Python tries to open `C:/Users/useraccount/folder/file.txt`

You should always try to get the absolute path of a file by using the different functions in the `os.path` module.

Answer (score 2):

If you use relative paths, they will be relative to the current working directory. To find out the current working directory, run the following code snippet from Python.

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

To avoid this, specify the absolute path.